# PHP & HTML: Download file link not working

Tags: php, html, laravel, hyperlink, download

The following code lists all the files contained in a certain folder in my local machine, as you can see I'm echoing the file path inside the  tag using the href attribute correctly.

So the problem is that when I click on the  tag, it doesn't take me to the file download unless I copy the link and paste it to another tab of the browser, why is this happening? How can I fix it?

```
<h5>Attached Files</h5>

<?php
    $date = $dateCreated->format('d-m-Y');
    $thepath = public_path().'/uploads/binnacle/'.$date.'/'.$activity->activity_id;

    $handle = opendir($thepath);
    $x = 1;
    while(($file = readdir($handle))!= FALSE) {
        if($file != "." && $file != ".." && $file != "thumbs" && $file != "thumbs.db") {

            echo $x.".- "."<a href='$thepath/$file' target='_blank'>$file</a><br>";

            $x++;
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
?>
```

NOTE: This happens with all file types including images, excel files, text documents, etc.

---

SOLUTION BY @WereWolf - The Alpha:

```
<?php
    $date = $dateCreated->format('d-m-Y');
    $thepath = "/uploads/binnacle/".$date."/".$activity->activity_id;

    $handle = opendir(public_path().$thepath);
    $x = 1;
    while(($file = readdir($handle))!= FALSE) {
        if($file != "." && $file != ".." && $file != "thumbs" && $file != "thumbs.db")
            {
            echo $x.'.- '.'<a href="'.asset($thepath.'/'.$file).'" target="_blank">'.$file.'</a><br>';
            $x++;
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
?>
```

Comment: Are you using Symfony or Laravel by any chance?

Comment: Where does it take you instead?

Comment: Plus, variables will not be echoe'd inside single quotes `'$thepath/$file'`

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'm using Laravel

Comment: @Fred-ii- Just modified it to this: `'<a href="'.$thepath.'/'.$file.'" target="_blank">'.$thepath.'/'.$file.'</a><br>'` and I get the same result

Comment: Try `echo $x.".- "."<a href=\"$thepath/$file\" target='_blank'>$file</a><br>";` that worked for me, yet I can't test the rest of your code though.

Comment: Then, follow the same idea for `'/uploads/binnacle/'.$date.'/'`

Comment: I understand, just tried your code it's still not working :/

Comment: Which code, the `echo $x.".- "."<a href=\"$thepath/$file\" target='_blank'>$file</a><br>";`? Plus, scratch the one about *"Then, follow the same idea for..."*

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yes that one

Comment: You'll need to `var_dump($thepath);` to see what's being passed through that variable then, and if possible to view the HTML source that's being generated by it and try to pinpoint where the quotes may be off. I think the problem may lie in `$thepath = public_path().'/uploads/binnacle/'.$date.'/'.$activity->activity_id;` plus the quote suggestion I gave you earlier.

Comment: Plus, try to add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I get the output like this: `<a href="C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\_THEAPP_\public/uploads/binnacle/19-06-2014/764086/1403221071_1400650841_14_select.png" target="_blank">1403221071_1400650841_14_select.png</a>`, do you think the error it's because of the combination of '\' and '/' in the URL?

Comment: It could be that. You'll need to play around with it a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make some changes:

```
// Remove the public_path()
$thepath = 'uploads/binnacle/'.$date.'/'.$activity->activity_id;
```

Then in the link:

```
"<a href='" . asset($thepath/$file) . "' target='_blank'>$file</a><br>";
```

Note: `Laravel` has a `File` component, You may use that, check it [in the source](http://laravel.com/api/class-Illuminate.Filesystem.Filesystem.html).

Comment: Also `Laravel` has a `File` component, You may use that, check it in the source.